# Как красиво отобразить std::tuple в отладчике VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, отладка

Использую CodeLLDB расширение. Почему-то `std::tuple{1, 42.0}` при отладке печатает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы было как в нормальных IDE `t: {1, 42.0}`?

Comment: `launch.json` покажите. У меня на убунте из коробки все нормально печатает. Какая ОС и компилятор?

Answer (score 0):

Вы в качестве компилятора должны поставить `clang` и библиотеку его `-stdlib=libc++`, иначе не все фичи работают. Сейчас у вас другой компилятор, скорее всего `gcc` с `-stdlib=libstdc++`. У меня то же самое с ним было.

Comment: Не воспроизводится. У меня работают все комбинации: GCC, Clang с libstdc++, Clang с libc++.